# How to display values from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        var data = Processor.LoadBarangays();
        List<BarangayModel> barangays = new List<BarangayModel>();

        **int totalConfirmed = 0;
        int totalPUI = 0;
        int totalPUM = 0;**

        foreach (var row in data)
        {
            ***totalConfirmed = +row.Confirmed;
            totalPUI = +row.PUI;
            totalPUM = +row.PUM;***

            barangays.Add(new BarangayModel
            {
                Barangay = row.Barangay,
                Confirmed = row.Confirmed,
                PUI = row.PUI,
                PUM = row.PUM
            });
        }

        return View(barangays);
    }
```

I have the above code for displaying this table: [red mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Aj0P.png) now I added the codes in emphasis above so that I can show it in the cards in blue mark: [blue mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW7G4.png). How can I display the values of the variables in the view? Can I use multiple views in a single controller? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you are looking for is show **multiple views in a single view**, as from the controller you can only return one, in your case `Dashboard` (when you dont specify, they have to be the same name as the method)

You can do that with partial views. and it depends a little bit in which version you are, if .NET framework, net core etc, also If you are using razor or any other framework for the front end. 
if you are using razor if you type `@HTML.Partial("viewname")` will load a partial view inside your "main" view. and you can send a model (an object) to it as second parameter `@HTML.Partial("viewname", model)`

for your example, you're returning `return View(barangays);` which is the red box.
then to include the blue ones  what you have to do is expand your model. so your `BarangayModel` should become a `DashboardModel` and one of the properties has to be `List<BarangayModel>` .

```
class DashboardModel{
   public List<BarangayModel> BarangayModelList {get;set;}
}
```

the reason to do this is because you have to add now, your red box. lest call the object PersonStatus and the example will be like:

```
class PersonStatus{
    int confirmed {get;set;}
    int recovered {get;set;}
    //rest of the properteis
}
```

and then you expand your `DashboardModel` to contain this new object:

```
class DashboardModel{
   public List<BarangayModel> BarangayModelList  {get;set;}
   public PersonStatus PersonStatus {get;set;}
}
```

so in your `Dashboard.cshtml` now you need to specify the new model.It is common to be in the first line of the view. And it looks like this `@model List<BarangayModel>` you will need to update it to `@model DashboardModel`

as you change for `List<BarangayModel>` to the new one, the foreach to print the table will fail. which means that you probably have something like `foreach(var bm in Model)` now you have to update it to `foreach (var bm in Model.BarangayModel)`

now you have both informations on the view, but you are only printing the `BarangayModel`

what you have to do is in the same folder as this view (or in the `Shared` one) create a view, which will receive the new `PersonStatus` object as parameter.

then you need to call it as a partial view from your main view, passing the parameter:

```
@Html.Partial("PersonStatusView", Model.PersonStatus);
```

or

```
<partial name="PersonStatusView" model="@Model.PersonStatus);
```

depends of which version/framework you're running.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I only have one problem now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRq5v.png

I can't access some of the properties of my BrgyModel(BarangayModelList) so that I can show it for my table header.

Comment: @Andrew are you using in the top of your partial view the `@model classnamehere`? if that's the case, are your properties `public`?

Comment: I am using @model DashboardModel. Yes it is all set to public.

   
<pre>
 public class DashboardModel
    {
        public List<BarangayModel> BrgyModel { get; set; }
        public PersonStatusModel PerStatusModel { get; set; }
    }<code>

Comment: @Andrew try to use `@Model` with an uppercase letter instead of `model`

Comment: Same results with the lowercase model. Sorry for bothering you. I just can't find the solution on the internet.

Comment:  are the properties inside the `BarangayModel` object also public? I just tried in one of my projects to do `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.object.property)` and it worked fine.

Comment: @Andrew that's very weird, I recommend you to open another post and maybe someone else will have some idea of what is going on. Just put in that post your model and the partial view. also, explain the error saying that `DisplayNameFor` seems not to be getting the properties of the object. sorry :/

Comment: You've done enough and thank you for all your help. Don't be sorry. I'm just curious that's why I want to solve it although I can use another way for the header text. Thank you.